# Out of memory with Sqs Akka Stream

Tags: scala, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, akka-stream, alpakka

Below code throws OOO on EC2 instance within 15 min of run (java config xms 1024 xmx2G) but doesn't throw any error when running on intellij.

```
SqsSource(queueUrl,
      //parallelism = maxBufferSize / maxBatchSize 20 10
      SqsSourceSettings().withWaitTime(10 seconds)
        .withMaxBatchSize(10).withMaxBufferSize(20)
    ).map {
      msg => {
        val out = Source.single(msg)
          .via(messageToLambdaRequest)
          .via(lambdaRequestToLambdaResp)
          .via(lambdaRespToAggregationKeySet)
          .via(workFlow)
          .log("error while consuming events internally.")
          .withAttributes(ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(decider))
          .runWith(Sink.seq)

        val reducedResponse = out.map(response => {
          response.foldLeft[Response](OK)((a, b) =>
            if (a == OK && b == OK) OK else NotOK)
        })

        val messageAction = reducedResponse
          .map(res =>
            if (res == OK) {
              //log.info("finally response is OK hence message action delete is prepared. {}.", msg.messageId())
              delete(msg)
            } else
              ignore(msg)
          )
        messageAction
      }
    }
      .mapAsync(1)(identity)
      .withAttributes(ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(decider))
      // For the SQS Sinks and Sources the sum of all parallelism (Source) and maxInFlight (Sink)
      // must be less than or equal to the thread pool size.
      .log("error log")
      .runWith(SqsAckSink(queueUrl, SqsAckSettings(1)))

  }
```

I tried this with 1.0-M3 and 1.0-RC1 both.
is there a work around of this?

top 5 object creation histogram using jhat -

```
Class   Instance Count  Total Size
class [C    1376284 2068640582
class software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.model.Message 332718  18632208
class java.lang.String  1375675 16508100
class [Lakka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask;    227 14880304
class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon   334396  5350336
```

Also I found similar issue here - https://github.com/akka/alpakka/issues/1588

I am wondering if some alternate available to solve this.

Comment: could you specify what exactly `delete`, `ignore` & all other intermediate functions return?

Comment: MessageAction; an API present in Alpakka sqs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either wait for the RC2/1.0.0 Alpakka releases, or you can create your own SQS source meanwhile, since it's not that many lines of code:

```scala
object MyVeryOwnSqsSource {

  def apply(
      queueUrl: String,
      settings: SqsSourceSettings = SqsSourceSettings.Defaults
  )(implicit sqsClient: SqsAsyncClient): Source[Message, NotUsed] =
    Source
      .repeat {
        val requestBuilder =
          ReceiveMessageRequest
            .builder()
            .queueUrl(queueUrl)
            .attributeNames(settings.attributeNames.map(_.name).map(QueueAttributeName.fromValue).asJava)
            .messageAttributeNames(settings.messageAttributeNames.map(_.name).asJava)
            .maxNumberOfMessages(settings.maxBatchSize)
            .waitTimeSeconds(settings.waitTimeSeconds)

        settings.visibilityTimeout match {
          case None => requestBuilder.build()
          case Some(t) => requestBuilder.visibilityTimeout(t.toSeconds.toInt).build()
        }
      }
      .mapAsync(settings.maxBufferSize / settings.maxBatchSize)(sqsClient.receiveMessage(_).toScala)
      .map(_.messages().asScala.toList)
      .takeWhile(messages => !settings.closeOnEmptyReceive || messages.nonEmpty)
      .mapConcat(identity)
      .buffer(settings.maxBufferSize, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
}
```

and then use it:

```scala
MyVeryOwnSqsSource(queueUrl,
      //parallelism = maxBufferSize / maxBatchSize 20 10
      SqsSourceSettings().withWaitTime(10 seconds)
        .withMaxBatchSize(10).withMaxBufferSize(20)
    ).map {
      msg => {
        val out = Source.single(msg)
          .via(messageToLambdaRequest)
          .via(lambdaRequestToLambdaResp)
          .via(lambdaRespToAggregationKeySet)
          .via(workFlow)
          .log("error while consuming events internally.")
          .withAttributes(ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(decider))
          .runWith(Sink.seq)

        val reducedResponse = out.map(response => {
          response.foldLeft[Response](OK)((a, b) =>
            if (a == OK && b == OK) OK else NotOK)
        })

        val messageAction = reducedResponse
          .map(res =>
            if (res == OK) {
              //log.info("finally response is OK hence message action delete is prepared. {}.", msg.messageId())
              delete(msg)
            } else
              ignore(msg)
          )
        messageAction
      }
    }
      .mapAsync(1)(identity)
      .withAttributes(ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(decider))
      // For the SQS Sinks and Sources the sum of all parallelism (Source) and maxInFlight (Sink)
      // must be less than or equal to the thread pool size.
      .log("error log")
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriel. I used akka-stream-sqs for now but i'll migrate to RC2 when it comes.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the OOM issue in existing Alpakka framework and get resolved in 1.0-RC2 - https://github.com/akka/alpakka/milestone/27

However as an alternate https://github.com/s12v/akka-stream-sqs work as charm ( though it is deprecated in favor of Alpakka Sqs)